# jQuery Fileupload and writing filename do MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to create a file uploader with jQuery, that uploads a file, renames it with a timestamp and registers it into a DB. Basically it it sends the file with a form to the server where a second script renames it and moves the file to the right directory. This works without any problem. The problem is, that I want to send also the table name where this DB Entry should be made.

So index.php contains the form:

```
<div id="uploaderMain">
        <p>Upload Your Files</p>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="./upload.php">
            <input type="file" name="images" id="images" />
            <input type="hidden" name="List" id="List" value="<?php echo $DBTable; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload Files!</button>
        </form>

    <div id="response"></div>
        <ul id="image-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The jQuery Code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./uploader/upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
        }
      });
```

The upload.php looks like this:

```
   <?php
//include db configuration file

include_once('../../db.php');

$List = $_POST['List'];

// get the time stamp for the uploaded file
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->getTimestamp();
// echo $date;


foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        // store the file name and the file ending in 2 variables
        $fileEnding = substr($name, -4,4);
        $fileName = substr($name, 0, (strlen($name)-4));
        $uploadName =  $fileName."_".$date.$fileEnding;
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "./uploads/" . $uploadName);
    }
}
```

after that I want to write to the DB. The problem is, that the $_POST['LIST'] statement doesn't provide my DBTable-name.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Cheers
Dan

Comment: What is the content of `formdata` in your ajax call?

Comment: some files (.png, .zip, .app) is it possible to send 2 vars?

Comment: It's possible. Can you print the content of `formdata` and do `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Are you sure it's populating the $_FILES array? I'm quite unsure Ajax does that.

Comment: post: array(0) { };

files: 
array(1) { 
  ["images"]=> array(5) { 
     ["name"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(7) "key.png" }
     ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php1eVZAs" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1434) } } }

Comment: a workaround that i tried is to print out the filename to a div in the second script and read it in in the first script again. the problem is, that the script starts before the filename is written to the div.

Comment: Be **very** careful when using posted data to determin where to insert values in the database. It's easy to manipulate this data end you don't want to end up having people adding records to other database tables (insert into 'permissions'?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add this to your jQuery code:

```
formdata.append('List', '[your value]');
```

Please note: in PHP everything that is a file will go into $_FILES. Everything else will go into $_POST.

If this does not work, make sure you also have the following code:

```
var formdata = new FormData();          
jQuery.each($('input[type="file"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formdata.append(i, file);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the source from browser if the `List` control has any value.